# IP Address Micro Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, cidr

We have an Azure web app that we use for dev\testing. I noticed in Application Insights that it is getting pinged like 500-700 times per minute. I tried blocking the IP in Networking and of course being no network expert didn't realize it will just keep rolling to the next one.

Question 1 is - How do I block by group of IP's used?

Question 2 if that doesn't work - How do I block the "U.K." as I only need in the US currently for dev\testing. I prefer question one so that I can use for my prod. version also and as needed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before blocking traffic, did you investigate what is causing the requests? It might be a health check of some kind.

Comment: Yes, it is an IP that comes up near the London Bridge I think... it is falling down lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1 is - How do I block by group of IP's used?

Create a new text file and store all the IP Addresses which you want to allow or block and each separated with a Comma (,) as shown below:

[image]

Paste this code in an PowerShell File to read the above text file:

``` Param``( ```

``` [``Parameter``(``Mandatory ``` `=` ``` $true``)] ```

`[string]` ``` $ResourceGroupName``, ```

``` [``Parameter``(``Mandatory ``` `=` ``` $true``)] ```

`[string]` ``` $WebAppName``, ```

``` [``Parameter``(``Mandatory ``` `=` ``` $true``)] ```

`[string]` `$IPAddressSourceFileName`

`)`

`#Step1 - Get All IP Addresses from the File`

`$SourceIPAddresses` ``` = (``Get-Content ``` ``` $IPAddressSourceFileName``).Trim() | ``` `ConvertFrom-Csv`

`#Step2 - Get All existing IP Addresses from the Config of App Service`

`$APIVersion` ``` = ((``Get-AzResourceProvider ``` `-ProviderNamespace` `Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes |` `Where-Object` `ResourceTypeName` `-eq` `sites).ApiVersions[0]`

`$config` ``` = (``Get-AzResource ``` `-ResourceType` `Microsoft.Web/sites/config` `-Name` `$WebAppName` `-ResourceGroupName` `$ResourceGroupName` `-ApiVersion` ``` $APIVersion``) ```

`#Step3 - Prepare the new IP Addresses list from that IPAddressList file and collect all the new ones into the $IpSecurityRestrictions collection`

``` foreach``(``$item ``` `in` ``` $SourceIPAddresses``){ ```

``` $Rule``=``$config``.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions | ``` `Where-Object` `{` ``` $_``.ipAddress ``` `-eq` ``` $item``.IPAddress} ```

``` if``(``$null ``` `-ne` ``` $Rule``) ```

`{`

`Write-Host` `-ForegroundColor` `Green` `'No Action on the IP:'` ``` $item``.ipAddress ```

`}`

`else`

`{`

``` $config``.Properties.ipSecurityRestrictions+=``$item ```

`}`

`}`

`#Step4 - Finally update the new IP Addresses to Azure App Service`

`Set-AzResource` `-ResourceId` ``` $config``.ResourceId ``` `-Properties` ``` $config``.Properties ``` `-ApiVersion` `$APIVersion` `-Force`

Run the above PowerShell Script from VS Code > Terminal > Run this following command:

```
.\ReadIPAddresses.ps1 azdevops-rg-eus-dev azuredevops-wapp1-eus-dev IPAddresses.txt
```

After running this command, you can see all the IP Addresses will be added to the Access Restrictions blade as shown here:

[image]

Comment: That is a great list of steps and I thank you for taking the time to teach me that. The issue is that it keeps changing the IP, every time I block, a new one is used. I am looking to see is there a way to block by the "batch of IP's" \ master CIDR, etc. ?

Comment: Hello @RickB, Use Azure Front Door and Web Application Firewall Option to block the IP addresses in CIDR i.e., Range Format and please visit these references [MSFT Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/419798/restrict-ips-from-accessing-azure-static-web-app-u.html) and [MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-configure-ip-restriction).

Comment: Great information, do you know how to get the entire range of IP's they could use based on many samples I have? Then it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Please refer this [article](https://piotr.gg/dev-ops/azure/collecting-ip-addresses-in-azure-app-insights.html) for collecting IP addresses from azure application insights information.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking arbitrary IP ranges brings you nowhere. If you really want to restrict access to your test environments on the network level, I suggest defining allowed IP ranges and blocking the rest of the internet. That can be done in the portal, using PS like HariKrishnaRajoli-MT showed or preferably with IaC like [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview?tabs=bicep) or [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/).

If you want to have some dynamic blocking (like country-based), you'll need a component in front of your App Service like an [Azure App GW with WAF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/custom-waf-rules-overview). However, that has some notable costs included.

Lastly, why is pinging an issue? It does not cause any significant stress to the service. If you want to protect your service from outside access, you should enable some authentication. Azure App Service [provides an easy way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) of enabling authentication and authorization with different identity providers.

Comment: Thank you, I was mainly also using this to help in case any future issues on production. Between all of your answers I can build the solution(s) that I need.